# How to separate these words by regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentense as below:

```
"I.UILISTNConsolidatedGroup: 8000Quarte: AnnualUnit: USD" or
"I.UILISTNDOUxConsolidatedGroup: 8000Quarte: FullUnit: VND"
```

I have to separate into 4 values from the sentence above: I.UILISTN, 8000, Annual, USD. I'm using index of to separate that, but it's seem so long and complex, please help me separate these values by regular expression (c#).
The words ConsolidatedGroup, Quarte, Unit are fixed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a working indexof solution (which works because you have enough fixed data within) you're almost definitely better off sticking with that. It will likely be faster than regex and give you fewer headaches.

Comment: one option could be using `Split` option, try this `"I.UILISTNConsolidatedGroup: 8000Quarte: AnnualUnit: USD".Split(new string[] {"ConsolidatedGroup:","","Quarte:","Unit:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual matching are almost always be faster then Regular Expressions.

```
string text = "I.UILISTNConsolidatedGroup: 8000Quarte: AnnualUnit: USD";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\w\.]+)ConsolidatedGroup: (\d+)Quarte: AnnualUnit: (\w+)");
var match = regex.Match(text);
foreach (var m in match.Groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

**Output:**

```
I.UILISTNConsolidatedGroup: 8000Quarte: AnnualUnit: USD
I.UILISTN
8000
USD
```